# Unable to solve the error "[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**Code**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *U1 =[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"img"]];

[DownloadManager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"img"]] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
    if (succeeded) {

        [cell.iconImgView setImage:image];

    }
}];
```

**Getting error**

> [__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Which line is causing the issue? The error seems explicit, but there are different lines where it could happens...

Comment: Are you working with Xcode 8?

Comment: This probably means that `dict[@"img"]` is returning an `NSNumber` representing a boolean and not an `NSString` as you expected.

Comment: None of the code posted calls `length`.

Comment: @Avi: `URLWithString:` will call internally `length`. `NSDictionary *dict = @{@"a":@(TRUE)};NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"a"]];` will cause the same error.

Comment: This is the dynamic language feature, is that cool? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
NSURL *U1 =[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"img"]];
```

The problem is caused by the fact that you assume:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"img"]
```

is returning an `NSString` when in fact it is returning an `NSNumber` representing a boolean value.

You need to either figure out why the data in the dictionary is incorrect or you need to use the correct key to get the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [ [dict objectForKey:@"img"] stringValue];
```

Use above mention code for getting string value