# Flutter app crash on startup (only IOS, both simulator and real device)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Android app works normal.

flutter version: stable 1.17.5

flutter doctor - everything ok

flutter pubs:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
device_preview: ^0.4.4
http: ^0.12.0+4
crypto: ^2.1.4
provider: ^4.0.5
get_it: ^4.0.1
flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
pin_code_fields: ^2.5.1
gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4
image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
intl: ^0.16.1
dio: ^3.0.9
mime: ^0.9.6+3
image_cropper: ^1.2.2
grouped_list: ^3.0.1
path_provider: ^1.6.9
open_file: ^3.0.1
url_launcher: ^5.4.10
table_calendar: ^2.2.3
smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
file_picker: ^1.12.0
month_picker_dialog: ^0.3.2
```

Can't find error, only print log is this :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean length]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I was looking for answer for 5 hours, did everything from flutter clean, deleted pods, Podfile.lock, updated Podfile, deleted and reinstalled all plugins, used all of flutter commands (flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub upgrade, pod repo update) nothing worked.

Comment: are you returning something from dictionary? then this might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793656/unable-to-solve-the-error-nscfboolean-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to

Comment: @AnkurLahiry I don't use objective c or swift, only dart except for flutter plugins. Maybe some library has issues, i don't know.

Comment: Can you run from xcode? maybe you'll get  a better log and post in your question

Comment: @JideGuru this is the log from xcode

Answer (score 0):

I found an error. In info.plist I removed by accident

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

and replaced it with

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<true/>
```

I pushed this change on Github and for a month I only tested app on Android, so nothing was showing that here was an error but finally I found it.